# Admin consent on behalf of all users to a third party app in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-tenancy

We are looking for a scenario where an admin can consent to a third party application on behalf of all users. So when a user logs into Sharepoint Online via the app, the user will not be asked to consent as the admin has already done. Is this possible on Sharepoint Online as of today? We are using CSOM for development.